# Remove injected script in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(
      null, {file : "app.js"});                                                                                                                                                                         
});
```

I am injecting a code like this to the extension on click. But I want to remove this injected code when the user clicks the extension Icon second time. How is it possible. The code Injects an html div with id "pluginHolder". I can manually remove it using the basic js code `document.getElementById('pluginHolder').remove();`.

How to do this process dynamically?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Removing a script" doesn't make any sense at all. By the time the icon is clicked the second time, your script already finished executing.

Comment: The script injects a div into the page. I just want to remove that div dynamicaly

Comment: So what you want is to inject another script to remove the `div`.

Comment: As mentioned, there is no way to "undo" what a content script did, nor a single method to "unload" it. You need to take care of cleanup yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution something like

```
if(document.getElementById('pluginHolder')) {
    document.getElementById('pluginHolder').remove()
} else {
   var pluginHolder = document.createElement('div');
   document.body.appendChild(pluginHolder);
}
```

If you want to affect js code and not DOM.
you can use play with `eventListener` ,

```
 function logMouse() {
      console.log(e.x+':'+e.y);
}
// Initialize on first run to true else use old value NOT(!) ( last time injected script)

isEnable = isEnable ? !isEnable : !!isEnable;
if(isEnable) {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', logMouse);
} else {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', logMouse);
}
```

Comment: NO, on first click it will inject app.js(this js injects an html file).

Comment: you can really inject html file. you can only inject js , so this why i offerd you a solution for injecting the same peace of code . that enable\disable its behavior each time its injected. there is no such thing as html injection . there is only js injection . i can explain further if you want

Comment: My app.js page injects a DOM element to the page. But in the background page there is  an ajax call also.

Comment: There is another way i better use the pop up with chrome.storage API